# Why does my Javascript function work when called with `onclick` but not when called programmatically?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a Javascript function that expands all panes of an ASP Ajax Accordion control. The function is:

```
function expandEditAll() {
  var behavior = $get("<%= accEditIncident.ClientID %>").AccordionBehavior;
  for (var i = 0; i < behavior._panes.length; i++) {
    behavior.get_Pane(i).content.style.display = 'inline';
    behavior.get_Pane(i).content.height = behavior.get_Pane(i).content.scrollHeight;
    behavior.get_Pane(i).content.style.height = behavior.get_Pane(i).content.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
}
```

When I call this function with:

```
<a href="#" onclick="expandEditAll();">Expand All</a>
```

it works perfectly.

But when I call it from C# code behind as follows:

```
StringBuilder expand = new StringBuilder();
expand.AppendLine("<script type='text/javascript'>");
expand.AppendFormat("  expandEditAll();" + System.Environment.NewLine);
expand.AppendLine("</script>");
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "expandEdit", expand.ToString(), false);
```

it doesn't work, and in Chrome Developer tools I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_panes' of undefined`. Why is `behavior` undefined here when I'm making the exact same function call?

I also tried:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "expandEdit", expand.ToString(), false);
```

but got the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $get is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I was able to execute the javascript function.

```
 StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();

 script.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>");
 script.Append(@"expandEditAll()");
 script.Append(@"</script>");

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "expandEdit",  script.ToString());
```

Comment: The problem is not that the function isn't executing; it's that I'm getting an `undefined` error on `var behavior` when the function is executed. At any rate, I tried your suggestion and it made no difference.

Comment: Yeah, as I looked more into your questions - its a bit more complicated than that.